# Error retrieving ExactTarget Campaigns from marketing cloud (fuel-sdk and ruby)

Tags: marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk

I'm getting a bizarre error attempting to retrieve my campaigns from the ET Marketing Cloud using the fuel sdk in ruby.

Following the default example used for List retrieval, it's working correctly:

```
client = FuelSDK::Client.new({'client'=> { 'id' => EXACTTARGET_CLIENT_ID, 'secret' => EXACTTARGET_CLIENT_SECRET }})

    list = FuelSDK::List.new
    list.client = client
    response = list.get
```

gives me a response like so:

```
[{:client=>{:id=>"XXXXXXX"}, :partner_key=>nil, :created_date=>Mon, 12 Jan 2015 17:01:13 +0000, :modified_date=>Mon, 12 Jan 2015 17:01:13 +0000, :id=>"4402", :object_id=>"bea2b746-7a03-4a50-9c94-ff89f387d443", :customer_key=>"All Subscribers - 52047", :list_name=>"All Subscribers", :category=>"52047", :type=>"Private", :description=>"Contains all subscribers", :list_classification=>"ExactTargetList", :"@xsi:type"=>"List"}]
```

However, if I try to use the given example for Campaigns:

```
campaign = FuelSDK::Campaign.new 
campaign.authStub = client #(NB: authStub or client? same error either way)
response = campaign.get
```

I'm immediately greeted with the following:

**`undefined method 'keys' for [{"id"=>""}]:Array`**

I'm pulling my hair out over this one, can anyone help me understand why this is happening for campaigns (and only campaigns?!)

Thanks.

Comment: Taking a look at this tonight - I'll see what I can uncover. Welcome to SFSE!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to build out the gem using the following command:

`gem build fuelsdk.gemspec`

Then install

`gem install fuelsdk-0.0.5.gem`

This should provide an up-to-date version with campaign support.

Comment: Pulling the .9 Refactor seems to be working correctly for campaigns. I'm going to cross-reference this with master, do some playing around, and then submit a pull request later.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad I could get you past it